"Deny from all" is adding in my all WordPress Sites's wp-content/uploads folder, disappearing media files
I am hosting my wordpress sites on godaddy's hosting cpanel. From last month i am having this issue with WordPress websites that media files are disappearing from media folder as well as webpages.Although these are present their numbering can be seen in media folder but empty boxes of images.What my observations are

Media files are present in wp-content/uploads folder but missing in media file in admin panel
URL of those files from media folder is also showing empty file while opening them from file manager is showing image
After inspecting there is .htaccess file automatically creating in wp-content/uploads directory which states rule "Deny from all"
removing that .htaccess file fixes problem but after one day that file again appears and site again brokes and m again deleting it sites works.

Tried Solutions:

multiple times did fresh installations and did settings from scratch(no backup uploading no old theme used)

Updated cpanel's password and scanned the whole site

No extra or security plugin is installed


But the problem persists with all hosted wordpress sites.Problem seems to be with hosting but i cant understand how automatically file is creating.
Any help appreciated.

Hello i faced the same issue these few days. I changed the .htaccsess file name into .htaccess_bak and my website works well now.
update:
this .htaccess show again today 

this post is not an answer, please leave a comment
